# iOS 14 Beta check PHAsset permissions for .limited access level

Tags: phasset, ios14

in iOS 14 beta, is there a way to check if the app has permissions to load a `PHAsset` image before trying to load it with `PHImageManager.requestImage?` This is for `PHAuthorizationStatus.limited` - when I fetch all assets in a `PHAssetCollection`, it returns those without permissions as well. I see an error object only when I try to load the image itself with `PHImageManager.requestImage` in the returned info object.

#### EDIT:

It turns out that this is a problem only on simulator. When I ran the app on a real device with iOS 14 beta, the `PHAssetCollection` fetch returned only those `PHAssets` that the user has granted access to.

Comment: I also encountered the same issue, opened a question on Apple Developers forum https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/657130

Comment: @kzamanov thanks for the edit. Works for me too on a real device.

Comment: Thank you for posting the followup comment.

Comment: Can't thank you enough for the edit comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here are something I've tested on a real device:

You can have access to all the `smart albums` (in the form of *PHAssetCollection*) even if you are in *Limited Photo Access* mode. However, you can fetch assets from these collections only if a user has explicitly selected it. It's meaningless to have a collection without any assets available.

You can NOT have access to any `user album` in *Limited Photo Access* mode.

It behaves a little differently on a simulator as you can have access to all the albums, no matter it is user album or smart album in *Limited Photo Access* mode. And you can fetch assets from these collections without limitations. However, you cannot get any data from these assets if the user haven't selected it. I performed a *requestImage* operation on an asset which I haven't selected in the popup and it failed with domain error code: -1.

Comment: One more thing, it is intended to make you have no access to any of the user album in *Limited Photo Access mode*. You can get more info [here at 11:11](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10641/) .

Answer (score -2):

try to add a predicate with mediaType, then fetch the result